# Access text files contained in a solution

Tags: c#

I have 3 text files in my solution (they are in the solution explorer) that I need to read in from. I don't want them copied to the output directory and they are marked as Embedded Resources. The path to them is `ProjectNamespace.Utility.Names.nameXXX.txt`

I need to access them in a class, also in the Names folder:

```
    public RandomName()
    {
        _prefixParts = PopulateFromFile("AoW.Utility.Names.namePrefix.txt");
        _middleParts = PopulateFromFile("AoW.Utility.Names.nameMiddle.txt");
        _suffixParts = PopulateFromFile("AoW.Utility.Names.nameSuffix.txt");
    }
```

What is the correct syntax to read in from these files?

**Update:** Here is the `PopulateFromFile` method in case it matters:

```
private static string[] PopulateFromFile(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllLines(path);
    }
```

**Update:** I'm attempting to implement the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16901400/1667020

**Update:** Well, I've gotten it to work at this point:

```
_prefixParts = PopulateFromFile(@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\AoW\AoW\AoW\Utility\Names\namePrefix.txt");
_middleParts = PopulateFromFile(@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\AoW\AoW\AoW\Utility\Names\nameMiddle.txt");
_suffixParts = PopulateFromFile(@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\AoW\AoW\AoW\Utility\Names\nameSuffix.txt");
```

How can I make the path local to the project?

Comment: I already looked at that one. It didn't answer my question. It's the folder hierarchy that is the problem.

Comment: So do you get any issues when running this code? FileNotFound?

Comment: This happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901736/mvvm-light-obtained-via-nuget-relaycommand-cs-not-found - When I comment out this code, the program runs.

Comment: This is in not a duplicate in my opinion...